# Use of void*, void ** and variadic function

Tags: c, variadic-functions, void-pointers

I want to write a function that frees as many pointers as wanted.
So I have this one :

```
void    myfree(size_t n, ...)
{
    void    **del;
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, n);
    while (n > 0)
    {
        del = va_arg(ap, void **);
        free(*del);
        *del = NULL;
        --n;
    }
    va_end(ap);
}
```

I call it like that :

```
char *one = malloc(x);
sometype_t *two = malloc(x);
myfree(2, &one, &two);
```

I assume that `one` and `two` are now pointing to NULL.
It seems to be working, but I'm still a bit worried. I did some researches about `void**` but I'm not sure if my function is really valid (UB are you there ?)

---

During my researches and tests, I tried some things I do not really understand.

Let's say we have this function

```
void    f(void **ptr)
{
}
```

If I call it like this

```
int *intptr = NULL;
f(&intptr);
```

I get a compiler warning : `warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int **' to parameter of type 'void **'`

So I tried this

```
int *intptr = NULL;
f( & ((void *)intptr) );
```

Compiler error : `error: cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'void *'`

But if I do

```
void *voidptr = NULL;
f(&voidptr); // I can take the address of a void pointer right ?
```

Actually `void*`, `void**` and conversions/casts with them are still unclear to me. That is why I'm worried about myfree() I posted above.
If any of you have some explanations I would be grateful  :)

Comment: from all the pointer types `void*` and `char*` are special. `void**` is not. I am too lazy to go further into details...

Comment: @bolov The special-ness of `void*` and `char*` do not directly apply to this post  other than `f( & ((void *)intptr) );`

Comment: Why are you passing the address of `one` and `two` to begin with? When you pass a pointer as a parameter, your function will receive a copy, but the copy holds the same address as the original allowing you to free the memory using a simple `void*` type rather than `void**`. (it's not like you are changing the starting address for a list here, you are just freeing memory)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Likely OP passes the address of the pointer to attempt `*del = NULL;`.

Answer (score 2):

First half code is likely OK yet may invoke *undefined behavior* (UB).

---

In *calling* `myfree(2, &one, &two);`, there are no conversions to `void *` nor `void **`.  The pointers `&one, &two` are passed unconverted as `char **`, `sometype_t **`.

It is the implementation of `myfree()` that assumes the pointers are a compatible type to `void **` when it does:

```
void ** del = va_arg(ap, void **);`
```

Salient specification:

> The `va_arg` macro expands .... If ... type is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument ..., the behavior is undefined  C11dr §7.16.1.1 2

The trick is that a pointer of `void **` may not be *compatible* with a `char **`, nor `sometype_t **`.  Since no *explicit* conversion is coded, this is only OK if those pointer types are *compatible*.  Although this is very likely on the many architectures, it is not specified and so UB.

---

With OP's 2nd half code, the conversion is done directly and the compiler warns:

> I get a compiler warning : warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int **' to parameter of type 'void **'

In this case the conversion is coded as part of `f(&intptr);`.  §7.16.1.1 2 does not apply here.  The specification of note:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.  C11dr §6.3.2.3 7

With decades of experience, I've never came across nor heard of a system that had *pointers to pointers* of different alignment. So this is low risk UB, yet I would heed the warning and code otherwise.

---

#### Alternative

Pass and expect to receive `void *` pointers. Note that this does not set the free'd pointer to `NULL`.

```
void myfree(size_t n, ...) {
  void *del;  // one *
  va_list ap;

  va_start(ap, n);
  while (n > 0) {
     del = va_arg(ap, void *);
     free(del);
     --n;
    }
  va_end(ap);
}
```

Character pointers are compatible with `void*` and do not require a cast.  Arbitrary object pointers need a cast.  This is similar to the need for the cast in `printf("%p\n", (void*) two);`

```
char *one = malloc(x);
sometype_t *two = malloc(x);
void *three = malloc(x);
myfree(3, one, (void*) two, three);
```

---

### Alternative 2

> I want to write a function that frees as many pointers as wanted.

Maybe instead of `myfree(n, ...)`, how about coding some of the more popular sizes, even as a macro, and leave it go at that?  This certainly meets the majority of coding needs and, of course, avoids a `myfree(3, p1, p2)` error.  Recall that is is OK to call `free4(p1, p2,p3,0);`

```
free2(void *p1, void *p2)`
free3(void *p1, void *p2, void *p3)
free4(void *p1, void *p2, void *p3, void *p4)
// maybe a few others
```

Comment: Thank's, I thought it was never necessary to cast into (void*). I need to do more researches about that ! Actually I'm not able to say when we (don't) need to cast in C. Let's go read the C11 standard  :)

Comment: @Gam For _object pointers_ (_function pointers_ are another beast), the need to cast is rare.  It is one of those C things that support many architectures which oblige it.  I doubt your code will have trouble without the casts.  Yet proper casting does do what is right that some compilers may warn  about.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard allows conversions to and from a `void *`, but not a `void **`.  On most implementation you're likely to come across they should be the same size, but there's no guarantee of that.  So this is undefined behavior.

This is one of those cases when a macro function makes the most sense, although you'll only be able to free one pointer at a time:

```
#define myfree(ptr) do { free(ptr); ptr = NULL; } while (0)
```

Answer (score 1):

as @dbush said in his answer your code has UB. If you want to keep your function then you can pass the pointer directly, free the memory and not modify the pointer. The setting to NULL is mostly useless anyway.

```
void myfree(size_t n, ...)
{
    void* del;
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, n);
    while (n > 0)
    {
        del = va_arg(ap, void *);
        free(del);
        --n;
    }
    va_end(ap);
}
```

```
char *one = malloc(x);
sometype_t *two = malloc(x);
myfree(2, one, two);
```

Comment: It is technically UB, but in practice I don't think there will be any chance for OP's code to fail. Setting a freed pointer to `NULL` will save many debug time if something goes wrong.

Comment: I think I got it, for example if sizeof(int**) > sizeof(void**),  a void** pointer can not hold the value of the int** pointer and the call to free() will fail ... right ?
But in practice all pointers type have the same size ... I need to check on that.

Comment: @Gam "all pointers type have the [same size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48827100/use-of-void-void-and-variadic-function/48830234#comment84662326_48827995)" No. C does not specify that, even though it is common on many platforms.  Even if the same size, they may not be   compatible without conversion.  C supports many architectures.